# How to update bidirectional @ManyToOne/@OneToMany relationship via REST from the inverse side

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have 2 entities in Spring Data Rest app:

```
@Entity
public class Question {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Answer {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    Question question;
    ...
}
```

and Spring Data repositories for both entities:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface QuestionRepository extends      PagingAndSortingRepository<Question, Long> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AnswerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Answer,     Long> {

}
```

Suppose I have Question with id 1 and two Answers with ids 1 and 2. 
Then I am able to link them like this:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/questions/1" http://localhost:8080/answers/1/question
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/questions/1" http://localhost:8080/answers/2/question
```

but NOT like this:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" -d $'http://localhost:8080/answers/1\nhttp://localhost:8080/answers/2' http://localhost:8080/questions/1/answers
```

Spring Data Rest processes the last curl request by fetching the Question instance with id 1, adding the two answers to its set and invoking hibernate merge on the Question.

The problem is that the changes are ignored since they are made from inverse (not owner of the relationship) side. And as far as I know you cannot change the owner or make it updateable from both sides in one-to-many/many-to-one relationship in hibernate.

Does that mean that I will have to update the answers set one-by-one?
Is it possible to configure Spring Data Rest so it will update the relation from the owners side so it gets persisted by hibernate?

Comment: Relationships in JPA are always unidirectional, unless you associate the parent with the child in both directions.

Comment: Can you post more specific what you want exaclty?

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `cascade` attribute to the `@OneToMany` annotation?

Comment: My relation is bidirectional - there is reference of Question in Answer and also there is reference to Answers in Questions.

Comment: Cascade implementation in general (any type of either org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade or javax.persistence.CascadeType) does anything only after entities have already been linked if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @HarshalPatil I want to find a way how to update one-to-many/many-to-one relationship (link more answers to one question) via     `curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" -d $'http://localhost:8080/answers/1\nhttp://localhost:8080/answers/2' http://localhost:8080/questions/1/answers`

Comment: Did you find an answer? This is exactly my problem? How do you update from the non-owner side?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Spring Data Rest.The reason (I think) that Spring Data Rest does not do this is the following:

A PUT request for an object means that it should be updated to have what you give to it (e.g the two answers for the question). However, if you later decide to PUT two different Answer objects on the uri list, where should the previous two Answer objects point to ? Should they be set to Null ? What if your model said @NotNull for the question field in the Answer entity?

In summary, updating an Answer to point to a different Question is well defined but updating the Question's answer list is not so well defined so Spring Data Rest avoids this. This of course is an estimated guess and I haven't looked at the code behind Spring Data Rest